# HDMI sound without overscan on open-source drivers?

Tags: sound, display, radeon, hdmi, open-source

Is there a way to have a regular scanned display with audio via an HDMI connection on open-source drivers? Possibly a way to force DVI video output over HDMI instead of 1080p?

Machine: Dell Studio laptop w/ Radeon Mobility HD3450 graphics, open-source drivers, I have tried this on both 12.04 and 12.10. TV/Monitor connected via HDMI.

- FGLRX drivers do not work for me (log in and only background shows up, yes I updated the kernals)
- I can turn underscan on and off in xrandr (which leaves me with either a zoomed out or in desktop).
- I have a cheap little TV with no overscan/underscan menu options.

---

**Situation 1:** HDMI sound is disabled by default.

**Result 1:** Info button on remote displays "DVI - 1920x1080@60Hz", image is perfect

---

**Situation 2:** HDMI sound is enabled via editing the GRUB.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.audio=1"
```

**Result 2:** Info button on remote displays "HDMI - 1080p", audio works, but display is overscan.

---

As stated in the title, the fglrx drivers **do not** work.

p.s. I have searched a lot, and have tried a few different fixes, however it is still very possible I missed something or made an error. Also, 99% of my Linux experience is Ubuntu, but I am still relatively new to Ubuntu and actually needing to use a command prompt/terminal to do things in an OS (I have taken university level coding classes before though).

Also, I know this question has been asked for AMD/ATI and received some answers, but none of the questions seem to address the overscan issue on open-source with an actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your monitor can only receive a limited number of HDMI resolutions, in addition, your laptop can only send a limited number of HDMI resolutions. Because your monitor and laptop are unable to find a common HDMI resolution you are getting over scan. The only solution is to add an HDMI/VGA adapter to  your set up. Audio output will still be through HDMI, however, the HDMI video output will be converted to VGA. Set your monitor to receive VGA input and you should end up with your monitors maximum native resolution, with everything fitting the way it should.